# Query on google fusion tables api always returns bad request

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables, bad-request

I'm seriously banging my head into the wall here - I created a fusion table with country boundaries. I'm calling those boundaries to a map and it works pretty fine until I hit a certain amount of arguments in the query.

The basic setup of the ft-call looks like this:

```
german_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: 'geometry',
                from: '18IEKtABiwgYqw2RGtiKlDqYiCysnmcxTczr81sNu'
            }, styles:[whiteLayer,zoneLayer,productLayer,countryLayer, matchLayer],
            map: map,
            styleId: 2,
            suppressInfoWindows: true
        });
```

The "layers" set in the styles contain different queries p.e. like this:

```
var zoneLayer = {
        where: "ISO_2DIGIT IN ('BE','NL','LU','AT','DK','LI','CH','CZ','FR','GB','GG','IM','MC','IT','PL','SK','SI','HU','VA','IE','PT','SE','ES','EE','FI','HR','LV','LT','NO','BA','BG','GR','IS','RO','RS','AD','HK','IN','SM','SG','ZA','TN','TR','AE','AL','CE','FO','GI','IC','XK','MK','MD','ME','RU','UA','BY','CA','MX','US','CN','ID','JP','KR','MO','MY','MT','TW','TH','VN','CY','EG','DZ','AR','AU','BH','BR','BN','CL','GP','IR','IL','YE','JO','KZ','QA','KW','LB','LY','MG','MA','MQ','MU','NG','OM','PK','PH','RE','BL','MF','SA','LK','SY','TK','TO','TT','TD','TC','TV','UG','UY','UZ','VU','VE','VI','VG','WF','CX','CF','AQ','BV','IO','TF','HM','PN','SH','GS','TM','UM','EH','JE','AX','SJ','DE')",
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#333333',
            fillOpacity: 0.2
        }
    };
var productLayer = {
        where: "ISO_2DIGIT IN ('AD','HK','IN','SM','SG','ZA','TN','TR','AE')",
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#E3758E',
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
    };
var countryLayer = {
        where: "ISO_2DIGIT IN ('XK')",
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#A90032',
            fillOpacity: 0.75,
            strokeWeight: 0,
            strokeOpacity: 0.00001
        }
    };
var matchLayer = {
        where: "ISO_2DIGIT IN ('AF','AO','AI','AG','AN','AM','AW','AZ','ET','BS','BD','BB','BZ','BJ','BM','BQ','BT','BO','BW','BF','BI','CK','CR','CW','DO','DM','DJ','EC','SV','CI','ER','FK','FJ','PF','GA','GM','GE','GH','GD','GL','GU','GT','GF','GN','GQ','GW','GY','HT','HN','IQ','JM','KY','KH','CM','CV','KE','KG','KI','CC','CO','KM','CD','CG','KP','CU','LA','LS','LR','MW','MV','ML','MP','MH','MR','YT','FM','MN','MS','MZ','MM','NA','NR','NP','NC','NZ','NI','NE','NU','NF','PS','PW','PA','PG','PY','PE','PR','RW','KN','LC','VC','PM','SB','ZM','AS','WS','ST','SN','SC','SL','ZW','SX','SO','SD','SS','SR','SZ','TJ','TZ','TL','TG')",
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#000000',
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }
    };
var whiteLayer = {
        where: "ISO_2DIGIT IN ('XXX')",
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
            fillOpacity: 0.0001,
            strokeWeight: 0,
            strokeOpacity: 0.00001
        }
    };
```

The whole thing works fine, until I hit an amount of ISO's bigger than 115. Then I just get back this 400:

```
NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i3!2i6!3i3!1m4!1m3!1i3!2i7!3i2!1m4!1m3!1i3!2i7!3i3!1m4!1m3!1i3!2i4!3i4!1m4!1m3!1i3!2i5!3i4!1m4!1m3!1i3!2i6!3i4!1m4!1m3!1i3!2i7!3i4!2m21!1e2!2sft%3A18IEKtABiwgYqw2RGtiKlDqYiCysnmcxTczr81sNu!4m2!1ssg!2s!4m2!1ssc!2sgeometry!4m2!1ssq!2s%24ISO_2DIGIT%2520IN%2520(%27AF%27%252C%27AO%27%252C%27AI%27%252C%27AG%27%252C%27AN%27%252C%27AM%27%252C%27AW%27%252C%27AZ%27%252C%27ET%27%252C%27BS%27%252C%27BD%27%252C%27BB%27%252C%27BZ%27%252C%27BJ%27%252C%27BM%27%252C%27BQ%27%252C%27BT%27%252C%27BO%27%252C%27BW%27%252C%27BF%27%252C%27BI%27%252C%27CK%27%252C%27CR%27%252C%27CW%27%252C%27DO%27%252C%27DM%27%252C%27DJ%27%252C%27EC%27%252C%27SV%27%252C%27CI%27%252C%27ER%27%252C%27FK%27%252C%27FJ%27%252C%27PF%27%252C%27GA%27%252C%27GM%27%252C%27GE%27%252C%27GH%27%252C%27GD%27%252C%27GL%27%252C%27GU%27%252C%27GT%27%252C%27GF%27%252C%27GN%27%252C%27GQ%27%252C%27GW%27%252C%27GY%27%252C%27HT%27%252C%27HN%27%252C%27IQ%27%252C%27JM%27%252C%27KY%27%252C%27KH%27%252C%27CM%27%252C%27CV%27%252C%27KE%27%252C%27KG%27%252C%27KI%27%252C%27CC%27%252C%27CO%27%252C%27KM%27%252C%27CD%27%252C%27CG%27%252C%27KP%27%252C%27CU%27%252C%27LA%27%252C%27LS%27%252C%27LR%27%252C%27MW%27%252C%27MV%27%252C%27ML%27%252C%27MP%27%252C%27MH%27%252C%27MR%27%252C%27YT%27%252C%27FM%27%252C%27MN%27%252C%27MS%27%252C%27MZ%27%252C%27MM%27%252C%27NA%27%252C%27NR%27%252C%27NP%27%252C%27NC%27%252C%27NZ%27%252C%27NI%27%252C%27NE%27%252C%27NU%27%252C%27NF%27%252C%27PS%27%252C%27PW%27%252C%27PA%27%252C%27PG%27%252C%27PY%27%252C%27PE%27%252C%27PR%27%252C%27RW%27%252C%27KN%27%252C%27LC%27%252C%27VC%27%252C%27PM%27%252C%27SB%27%252C%27ZM%27%252C%27AS%27%252C%27WS%27%252C%27ST%27%252C%27SN%27%252C%27SC%27%252C%27SL%27%252C%27ZW%27%252C%27SX%27%252C%27SO%27%252C%27SD%27%252C%27SS%27%252C%27SR%27%252C%27SZ%27%252C%27TJ%27%252C%27TZ%27%252C%27TL%27%252C%27TG%27)%24ISO_2DIGIT%2520IN%2520(%27AQ%27%252C%27BV%27%252C%27IO%27%252C%27TF%27%252C%27HM%27%252C%27PN%27%252C%27SH%27%252C%27GS%27%252C%27TM%27%252C%27UM%27%252C%27EH%27%252C%27DE%27)%24ISO_2DIGIT%2520IN%2520(%27XXX%27)%24ISO_2DIGIT%2520IN%2520(%27AF%27%252C%27AO%27%252C%27AI%27%252C%27AG%27%252C%27AN%27%252C%27AM%27%252C%27AW%27%252C%27AZ%27%252C%27ET%27%252C%27BS%27%252C%27BD%27%252C%27BB%27%252C%27BZ%27%252C%27BJ%27%252C%27BM%27%252C%27BQ%27%252C%27BT%27%252C%27BO%27%252C%27BW%27%252C%27BF%27%252C%27BI%27%252C%27CK%27%252C%27CR%27%252C%27CW%27%252C%27DO%27%252C%27DM%27%252C%27DJ%27%252C%27EC%27%252C%27SV%27%252C%27CI%27%252C%27ER%27%252C%27FK%27%252C%27FJ%27%252C%27PF%27%252C%27GA%27%252C%27GM%27%252C%27GE%27%252C%27GH%27%252C%27GD%27%252C%27GL%27%252C%27GU%27%252C%27GT%27%252C%27GF%27%252C%27GN%27%252C%27GQ%27%252C%27GW%27%252C%27GY%27%252C%27HT%27%252C%27HN%27%252C%27IQ%27%252C%27JM%27%252C%27KY%27%252C%27KH%27%252C%27CM%27%252C%27CV%27%252C%27KE%27%252C%27KG%27%252C%27KI%27%252C%27CC%27%252C%27CO%27%252C%27KM%27%252C%27CD%27%252C%27CG%27%252C%27KP%27%252C%27CU%27%252C%27LA%27%252C%27LS%27%252C%27LR%27%252C%27MW%27%252C%27MV%27%252C%27ML%27%252C%27MP%27%252C%27MH%27%252C%27MR%27%252C%27YT%27%252C%27FM%27%252C%27MN%27%252C%27MS%27%252C%27MZ%27%252C%27MM%27%252C%27NA%27%252C%27NR%27%252C%27NP%27%252C%27NC%27%252C%27NZ%27%252C%27NI%27%252C%27NE%27%252C%27NU%27%252C%27NF%27%252C%27PS%27%252C%27PW%27%252C%27PA%27%252C%27PG%27%252C%27PY%27%252C%27PE%27%252C%27PR%27%252C%27RW%27%252C%27KN%27%252C%27LC%27%252C%27VC%27%252C%27PM%27%252C%27SB%27%252C%27ZM%27%252C%27AS%27%252C%27WS%27%252C%27ST%27%252C%27SN%27%252C%27SC%27%252C%27SL%27%252C%27ZW%27%252C%27SX%27%252C%27SO%27%252C%27SD%27%252C%27SS%27%252C%27SR%27%252C%27SZ%27%252C%27TJ%27%252C%27TZ%27%252C%27TL%27%252C%27TG%27)!4m2!1sc!2zZzpEQzAwMzI7cDozMztxOjAkZzpkYzAwMzI7cDo4MDtxOjAkZzpGRkZGRkY7cDowO3E6MCRnOkE5MDAzMjtwOkJGO3E6MCRnOkRDMDAzMjtwOjgw!4m2!1sy!2s2!4m2!1sgmc!2sxxxclientidxxx!5i1!3m3!2sde!3sUS!5e18!4e3!12m1!5b1&callback=_xdc_._fx69lb&token=42488
```

The "xxxclientidxxx" is a placeholder of course.

Can anyone think of a possible problem here? Is there a maxium of query arguments on ft-queries? I'm pretty lost.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems there is no solution for the problem in that post. The URL length is below 2048.

Comment: I count 3892 characters in the URL you posted.